# How do I make a movieclip appear randomly all over the scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, random, actionscript

I'm planning a shooting game for which I want to have a certain "enemy" appear randomly all over the place once at a time to make it able to be shot while appearing. So I have to make it appear and disappear, then appear once again in a different location and possibly a different size.

The code is this one I tried to put for the randomly appearing movieclip

```
parent.enemy3.x=(Math.random()* 400) + 70;
parent.enemy3.y=(Math.random()* 300) + 70;
escale= Math.random() + 0.2;
parent.enemy3.scaleX = escala;
parent.enemy.scaleY = escala;
```

I put this code in a second layer inside the movie clip all along its animation that appears and disappears. However it doesn't seem to work, the error that I get is that the instance of the movieclip is not an undefined property and then it says the escale is not defined either.

What should I do to make it work? Is there something missing in the code?

Comment: What is your question? Is there a problem with the code? Did you test it? Do you not know how to add movieclips to the scene?

Comment: Well, it's more like, I tested it and I didn't make it work and I don't know why, and yes I do know how to do so. I will edit my question including a few things I tried just now.

Comment: You should define excale, var excale:Number = Math.random() + 0.2

Comment: Sorry, your information is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use codes in frames 
use in seperates classes 
anyway your code look correct if of course you had defined your escale before 
like

`var escale:Number = 1;`

also plase a code to the beginning and check the trace

```
trace(parent.enemy3);
```

maybe your enemy3 is not located in the parent level of current movieclip

Comment: Thank you, I found that the problem was that I had to use this.enemy instead of parent.enemy... :)